# Configure VSCode for c++ dev in linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

main.cpp:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Throws an exception

> undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'

i have this library in

> /usr/include/X11/

VSCode prompts #include X11/Xlib.h so I guess he knows where to look for the library.
Build task:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "linux64",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Headers/",
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Sources/main.cpp",
            "-o",
            "HW"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true,
        }
    }
]
```

Help me to configure VSCode plz

upd:
Work with

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "linux64",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++-8",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/Sources/main.cpp",
            "-L",
            "/usr/include/X11/",
            "-lX11",
            "-o",
            "HW"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true,
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: You are missing the library to link with, e.g. `-lX11` (that's little L) and you will probably need the `-L /path/to/X11/lib` to provide the *library search path*. The `undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'` is a *linker* error telling you the linker can't find where the function `XOpenDisplay` is *defined*, as the compiler found the *declaration* in the header.

Comment: I am suggesting you to install Linux Subsystem on Windows. I discovered it lately and it helped me a lot.

Comment: @PeMaCN try and avoid suggesting somebody install additional software to solve a problem another way. The question asks about a simple compilation problem, not what other software can do it better. The exact same problem would exist no matter what software is installed. A more apt suggestion would be to open the Developer Command Prompt and learn how to compile and link using external libraries from the command line -- so you then can tell VS what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VSCode prompts #include X11/Xlib.h so I guess he knows where to look for the library

No, it does not.

Undefined refence is linking error. You have to specify X11 library with `-l` option and its location with `-L` option when you compile your code. E.g.

`g++ main.cpp -lX11library  -L /path/to/X11/lib`

Comment: You also have to tell the linker which library to link with by including the `-lLibrary` in the compile string as well.

Comment: ooops, missed that